# Hibernate many to many relation with two tables

Tags: mysql, hibernate, many-to-many, associations

I have database table structure like below :
[image]

Without thinking of DB assume that I m putting some products into a List of product.Problem I m having is when I try to fetch data like `qnty` of a product which size is SMALL or calculating products with same size and product id inside the list  **`prodct.getProductHasSizes().`** returns a set of **ProductHasSize**.Get rid of the associative table can solve this problem ??? But `qnty` column is inside that.Any help would be grateful to me. I suppose my problem is clear to you. Sorry about my English.Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
public boolean addToCart(Product p) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for (Product prodct : shoppingList) {
        if (prodct.isSameProduct(p)) {

            //here i have the problem I wanted to increase the quantity if the same product is adding.But below code returns set.
            //  prodct.getProductHasSizes().
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        this.shoppingList.add(p);
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;

}
```

Comment: No, it's not clear at all. Saying "I'm having problems" doesn't tell us anything about the problem you're facing. Post your code, tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: Still very unclear. It seems that you have a shopping cart, containing a bought products, along with the number of bought items for each product. Something like "John has bought 5 T-shirts and 4 hoodies". The quantity here has nothing to do with the quantity in the product_has_size table, which seems to say: "the store has 250 t-shirts of size M, 125 t-shirts of size L, and 30 hoodies of size XL". The quantity in the shopping cart and the quantity in the product_has_size table are thus not the same, and you shouldn't increment the quantity in product_has_size when someone buys a product.

Comment: Yes. I dont increment the quantity . Lets forget about the data base for a while . Assume that I have a ArrayList<Porduct> and adding products to it. Is it clear ??

Comment: Each time I ' m adding  a product to the list I have to check if the product is already exist in the list of Product. If so I'm increasing the qnty without adding the product into the list. Products can be like you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Not at all. The code says you want to access getProductHasSizes() to increment the quantity. Now you say you don't want to increment the quantity. And then the next comment says that you're incrementing the quantity. So, what's the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to find and increment the quantity of a Product in the List<Product> not the Database. Think It as a session cart.

Comment: Then either store the same product multiple times, and count them, or store instances of BoughtProduct in the cart, where BoughtProduct would have a field of type Product containing the bought product, and a field of type int named `numberOfBoughtItems`.

Comment: What about my approach ?? Is it bad ?? I just need to know how to get the product qnty form Product instance.

Comment: Because in this case qnty is not in the Product Entity class. And ** prodct.getProductHasSizes()** also returns Set.

Comment: You don't have any approach. All you have is a comment saying that you would like to increment the productHasSize quantity, and I told you that this quantity has nothing to do with the number of bought items in the cart and should thus not be incremented. There is no "bought quantity" in the model you posted. So you need an additional class, which stored the bough quantity of a product in a cart. That is radically different from the remaining quantity in the stock.

Comment: K. I'll try with separate class. Thank you so much for your time.